# Efficiency of Using SVG Icon in React App

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, svg

I am considering using icon as inline SVG in React Project with typescript and nextjs.

what is better benefited using inline svg instead of using image or icon font?

I think using inline SVG is more easy to maintain much icons. and other thing?

Especially, how about performance? is there any specific difference? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think inline SVG elements are better at:

- [changing icon color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/color)
- [adding animation icon](https://css-tricks.com/animating-svg-css/)
- rendering effectively when [you are using bundler](https://engineering.fb.com/web/facebook-redesign/)

I would recommend you to use SVG bundler plugin, loader or generator such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/@svgr/webpack, rather than managing SVG icons yourself.